# Access Azure Storage from C# Azure Function

Tags: azure-function-app

I am trying to access content from the Blob Storage from an Azure function. I have the following:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{   
    string path = req.Query["path"];   

    string storageConnectionString = "...";
    CloudStorageAccount blobAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = blobAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("content");
    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(path);*

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Content = /* to do - content of blob */
    };    
}
```

However, I am struggling to tell the function to recognize Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage namespace:

```
2019-11-07T09:59:57.729 [Error] run.csx(7,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WindowsAzure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I feel I am missing something major in my understanding of Azure Functions, as it should not be such a challenge to pull in namespaces/packages to work with Azure from within an Azure function.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any update on this issue? Could you access the storage file now or did you still have other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In c# script Function, you don't need to init blob client to read blob. Azure function provides the Blob binding to read/write blob, check this doc:[Blob Input - example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=csharp-script#input---example).

Firstly go to your function Integrate, set it like the below pic. With this just bind the `inputBlob` to stream to read content or bind to `CloudBlockBlob` type and just use the `CloudBlockBlob` method.

And the path supports bind to container, and in the function just bind to `CloudBlobContainer` type.

[image]

The below is my test code to read a text file.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static void Run(HttpRequest req, Stream inputBlob,ILogger log)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputBlob);
    string  oldContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    log.LogInformation($"oldContent:{oldContent}");  
}
```

[image]

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.